# Firebase Push ID - how to generate it as a child node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't figure out how this is made - I need the exact same thing, but when I do push I get object with nodes which I don't want. Anyone knows how to do this like below:

```
    {
    "messages": {
        "-JhLeOlGIEjaIOFHR0xd": "Hello there!",
        "-JhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq": "Push IDs are pretty magical.",
        "-JhQ7APk0UtyRTFO9-TS": "Look a white rabbit!"
    }
}
```

Source: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

What I try now:

```
var key1 = firebase.database().ref('places/a/schedules').push().key;
var val1 = "nice title";

firebase.database().ref('places/a/schedules').set({
    [key1]: val1
});
```

This gives me what I want, but when new one is created all the other nodes are gone. When I use `push()` then I get object with received key from `push().key` so it's also not what I want.

Comment: Please show your code.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson - just updated my question with relevant code.

Comment: whats wrong with `firebase.database().ref('places/a/schedules').push("nice title")`

Comment: Oh man, why it's nowhere in documentation? This saved me!! Thank You @mohamadrabee - what didn't I found out earlier that `push` can accept arguments...

Comment: see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Comment: It's the same as `firebase.database().ref('places/a/schedules').push().set("nice title")`. So I don't think the crucial bit is that `push()` is overloaded, but more that you can call it on any location ([`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference) in Firebase speak).

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.databse().ref('messages').push().set("Hello there!");
```

or

```
 var db=firbase.database().ref();
 db.child('messages').push().set("hello there!");
```

this will work